# Rails grab array of Params and display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a form with checkboxes where you can choose which email addresses to send the message to.

after the user submits the form I want to be able to grab those list of email addresses and display them in the view

The email address is not being saved in the database and there is no column on the model (email_recipients)

how can i list the user email address in the view ?

the valid params on the model are

```
 def messsage_params
   params.fetch(:message).permit(:message_content, email_recipients:[]).merge(user: current_user,         project: project)
 end
```

I've tried doing

```
 message.email_recipients
```

but i get undefined email_reicipents

i am able to do

```
message.message_content
```

but im guessing its because its an actual field on the database

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SFZWLDcD9guqk4kGWCP5w0JiyfnPDxnDSJsNy0WVh1U=", "message"=>{"email_recipients"=>["user@example.com"], "message_content"=>"df"}, "project_id"=>"3f33f"}

Comment: thats the actual processed params but i'm unsure how to grab the email_recipient and display it in my views

Comment: what is wrong with `params[:message][:email_recipients]`?

Comment: I get undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: messsage_params[:email_recipients] if you want to call the message_params method from the view you can call the macro helper_method :message_params from the controller